# Unable to pick-up date using v-calendar

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, calendar, vcalendar

I would like to use v-calendar to pick up dates in a textarea in my Laravel application.

If I follow the official documentation and use the code to use v-calendar from CDN, I can pick up the date from v-calendar.

However, if I use the same code to set the vue-component to pick up the dates from v-calendar, I cannot pick up the dates.

official document:
https://vcalendar.io/examples/datepickers.html

**datepick.blade.php** in case CDN

```js
<script>
new Vue({ 
  el: '#cal',
  data: {
    days: [],
    date: "",
  },
  computed: {
    dates() {
    return this.days.map(day => day.date);
  },
  attributes() {
    return this.dates.map(date => ({
      highlight: true,
      dates: date,
    }));
   },
  },
  methods: {
    onDayClick(day) {
    const idx = this.days.findIndex(d => d.id === day.id);
    if (idx >= 0) {
      this.days.splice(idx, 1);
    } else {
      const date = this.date;
      if(date === "") {
        this.date = (day.id.slice(5).replace("-", "/")) + " 19:00";
      } else {
        this.date = date + "\n" + (day.id.slice(5).replace("-", "/")) + " 19:00";
        }
      }
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

```html
<div class="event-datepicker-wrapper" id="cal" ref="days">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/v-calendar/lib/v-calendar.min.css'>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/v-calendar'></script>

  <div class="create-date">
    <textarea rows="10" name="kouho" v-model="date" class="form-textarea event-choice-textarea" ></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="calender-wrapper">
    <div class="calender">
      <v-calendar :attributes="attributes" @dayclick="onDayClick" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="calender-wrapper">
  <div class="calender">
  <v-calendar :attributes="attributes" @dayclick="onDayClick" />
  </div>
```

**app.js**

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('calendar', require('./components/Calendar.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**Calendar.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="event-datepicker-wrapper" ref="days">
    <div class="create-date">
      <textarea
        rows="10"
        name="kouho"
        v-model="date"
        class="form-textarea event-choice-textarea"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="calender-wrapper">
      <div class="calender">
        <v-calendar :attributes="attributes" @dayclick="onDayClick" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VCalendar from "v-calendar";
Vue.use(VCalendar);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      days: [],
      date: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    dates() {
      return this.days.map(day => day.date);
    },
    attributes() {
      return this.dates.map(date => ({
        highlight: true,
        dates: date,
      }));
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onDayClick(day) {
      console.log(day);
      const idx = this.days.findIndex((d) => d.id === day.id);
      //   console.log(format(day.id));
      console.log(idx);
      if (idx >= 0) {
        this.days.splice(idx, 1);
      } else {
        const date = this.date;
        if (date === "") {
          this.date = day.id.slice(5).replace("-", "/") + " 19:00";
        } else {
          this.date =
            date + "\n" + day.id.slice(5).replace("-", "/") + " 19:00";
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**datepick.blade.php** in case vue-components

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="event-date-wrapper">
    <calendar></calendar>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: Could you create a reproducible case in codepen.io?

Comment: The following link is a reproducible case of date-picker when using CDN in  codepen.io.
https://codepen.io/sfxsnbtx-the-sasster/pen/zYwMOKv

Comment: I could not create a reproducible case of the Vue-component version. I'll share it as soon as I can create.

Comment: I solved this issue by deleting a code <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer /> in datepick.blade.php. But, I do not understand why the issue was resolved. I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me a reason. Thanks!